# UPDATE SET Não funciona em MariaDB

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tenho o seguinte código no phpmyadmin, MariaDB

```
UPDATE bairro SET 
  NM_BAIRRO = 'Bairro'
 ,CD_CIDADE = 1
 ,CD_ZONA = 1
 WHERE CD_BAIRRO = 1
```

Alguém consegue me dizer, só porque esse comando não funciona?

Comando em php:

```
 public function update (Bairro $bairro){
        $this->connection =  null;
        $teste = false;
        $this->connection = new ConnectionFactory();
        //echo "Bairro: ".$bairro->getNmBairro();
        $this->connection->beginTransaction();
        try{
            $query = "UPDATE `bairro` SET 
                              `NM_BAIRRO`=:bairro
                             ,`CD_CIDADE`=:cidade
                             ,`CD_ZONA`=:zona 
                             WHERE `CD_BAIRRO`=:codigo";
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(":bairro", $bairro->getNmBairro(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":cidade",$bairro->getCidade()->getCdCidade(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(":zona",$bairro->getZona()->getCdZona(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(":codigo", $bairro->getCdBairro(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->connection->commit();

            $teste =  true;


            $this->connection =  null;
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Erro: ".$exception->getMessage();
        }
        return $teste;
    }
```

A função que eu chamado

```
function change($id, $nome, $cidade, $zona){
    // echo "<script>alert('Adicionar'); </script>";

    require_once "../beans/Bairro.class.php";
    require_once "../controller/BairroController.class.php";
    require_once "../beans/Cidade.class.php";
    require_once "../beans/Zona.class.php";

    $bairro = new Bairro();
/*    echo "Codigo do bairro: ".$id."<br>";
    echo "Codigo do Cidade: ".$cidade."<br>";*/
    $bairro->setCdBairro($id);
    $bairro->setNmBairro($nome);
    $bairro->setCidade(new Cidade());
    $bairro->getCidade()->setCdCidade($cidade);
    $bairro->setZona(new Zona());
    $bairro->getZona()->setCdZona($zona);
    $bairroController = new BairroController();
    $teste = $bairroController->update($bairro);

    if($teste)
        echo json_encode(array('retorno' => 1));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('retorno' => 0));
}
```

meu form

```
<?php
require_once "beans/Bairro.class.php";
require_once "controller/BairroController.class.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];

$bairroController = new BairroController();
$bairro = new Bairro();
$bairro = $bairroController->getBairro($id);



include "include/head.php"; ?>

<form method="post" id="form">
                    <input id="id" value="<?php echo $bairro->getCdBairro(); ?>" type="hidden">
                    <input id="acao" value="A" type="hidden">
                    <input id="id-cidade" value="<?php echo $bairro->getCidade()->getCdCidade();  ?>" type="hidden">
                    <input id="id-zona" value="<?php echo $bairro->getZona()->getCdZona();  ?>" type="hidden">
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                        <label for="bairro">Bairro</label>
                        <input id="bairro" class="form-control" required="" value="<?php echo $bairro->getNmBairro(); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
                        <select id="cidade" class="form-control" required="">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 form-group" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                        <label></label>
                        <a href="#" title="Clique para atualizar a lista" class="btn btn-refresh"><i class="lnr lnr-sync"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        <label for="zona">Zona</label>
                        <select id="zona" class="form-control" required="">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 form-group" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                        <label></label>
                        <a href="#" title="Clique para atualizar a lista" class="btn btn-refresh1"><i class="lnr lnr-sync"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="salvar()">Salvar</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-voltar" data-url="pais.php" onclick="return verifica('Tem certeza de que deseja cancelar a opera&ccedil;&atilde;o?');">Cancelar</a>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

meu Controller

```
 public function update (Bairro $bairro){
        require_once ("../model/BairroDAO.class.php");
        $bairroDao = new BairroDAO();
        $retorno = $bairroDao->update($bairro);
        return $retorno;
    }
```

Comment: Não funciona o quê? Qual o erro?

Comment: Não dá erro, dá mensagem de sucesso apenas, mas não há alteração. Apenas 0 Linha afetada

Comment: Defina o problema por favor, responda as seguintes questões: 1. Está usando isso no PHP com mysqli ou PDO? 2. Se executar via phpmyadmin ou diretamente no terminal este problema ocorre? Está usando "transaction"?

Comment: estou usando 1: PDO, no phpadmyadmin estou usando transaction

Comment: No phpmyadmin funciona

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: justamente esse método não funciona e olha que eu segui o mesmo padrao de todos os outros

Answer (score 0):

Olha só
Como eu codigo da zona do bairro é int o sistema estava obtendo o nome e na hora de dar o update não funcionada

Simplesmente era porque no combobox eu juntei as palavras

```
<selec>
 <option selectedvalue="1">Leste</option
</select>
```

e o correto

```
<selec>
 <option selected value="1">Leste</option
</select>
```

Por isso não salvava..

Obrigado ao que tentaram me ajudar